# Get value of number and reverse it

Tags: java, math

I have a function which is being called every second (just an example), and I need to take the integer it is being given, and reverse it.

Say I have 10 numbers, 1-10. If it inputs 10, return 1. 9, return 2, onward. I need to be able to take the input, and return it's opposite.

Here's a programming example:

```
public int getReversedValue(int input)
{
    switch(input)
    {
        case 0: return 10;
        case 1: return 9;
        case 2: return 8;
        case 3: return 7;
        case 4: return 6;
        case 5: return 5;
        case 6: return 4;
        case 7: return 3;
        case 8: return 2;
        case 9: return 1;
        case 10: return 0;

        default: return 0;
    }
}
```

The reason I don't use what's shown above is because I'm dealing with an integer as large as 250, so this doesn't quite seem efficient.

Comment: Can I get an example? Stating I need subtraction does not help much. I don't it spelled out, just a concept or code snippet to replace my method above.

Comment: What is the opposite of `250`?

Comment: Do you mean you want to invert each digit individually?  So 237 for example would become 873?  Or do you mean something different?  Please clarify.

Comment: In order to do that you should have a limit. In you case it is `10`. So, just calculate `limit - input` to get your desired number. Or clarify your answer :D.

Comment: @Tom , I can assign a limit. Thanks.

Comment: What's the reverse of one, ten and one hundred? I think you need a `String`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To "reverse" a number as you have described it, try this:

If the maximum number is `n`, the "opposite" is `n+1` minus the given number.

EDIT: To account for differences in the starting number, the formula is:

`starting number` + `ending number` - `given number`

For example, with the list `{3, 4, 5, 6}`, going from `6` to `3` is given by `6 + 3 - 6`, which is `3`.

Comment: If `n` is 10, your formular would return 5 for the input 6. That doesn't seem to be right.

Comment: That depends on whether the numbers start with 0 or 1. I'll update to be most precise.

Comment: The idea is I have an integer, labeled "distance". Relative to distance, I need to get how much radiation my entity is recieving. So if I am at a distance of, say 4. I need a function that'd return the radiation (int) I am recieving as the "opposite" of distance.

If max = 10, and I am at a distance of 4, I should recieve a "radiation" level of 6. If I am at 11 or above, I need to return 0.

Comment: And if the max is 100, and I am at a distance of 35, I need to return a radiation level of 65 (To add up to the maximum)

Comment: All right, then just use the above formula with a starting number of 0. So it would simply be `max - distance`, in your case.